# PHP header strange behaviour after processing URL

Tags: php, url, header

On my website i am using quite amount for GET parameters in url for loading specific page. And some of available actions involve calling another GET parameter in order to do something (`..&act=something`). PHP file with this actions is included at the top of the page. Below of this inclusion i have some code that checks if URL is valid, otherway header will head you to the correct one.

Lets say i have added a player as a friend. 
Requested URL will be for example:

`?id=3&request=clan&act=add&target=5`.

So going by this url i am supposed to go in `case: 'add'` part and later being redirected by that header. However what i have is that this header is ignored. Instead, i am redirected by checking part. What is more odd, added friend appears in my friend list. Why does this happenes?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['act']))    //this code is included
{
    switch ($_GET['act'])
    {
        case 'add':
            //do something
            header('Location: /index.php?id='.$cuid.'&request=clan&section=members');
        break;
    }
}

//some other code

if ($_GET['request'] == 'clan')
{
    if ((!isset($_GET['section']) || ($_GET['section'] == '')) && ($c_guid != 0))
    {
        header('Location: /index.php?id='.$cuid.'&request=clan&section=info');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Add `exit` or `die` after `header`.

Comment: Both headers will be sent here. Just add an `exit` or something similar after the first redirection.

Comment: Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: @CasBloem yup, i am awared of this common mistake, however this is not the case, but ty for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputting a `header` does not actually stop your script! All the other code is running as well. You need to explicitly `exit` if you do not want any further code to be executed.